# Should UDP socket creation & communication only be done in the main function?

Tags: c, udp

This is probably a stupid question, but I couldn't find the answer.
I'm trying to write a module(say, module A) where it reads files and sends the data to another module(module B). What I originally planned was to make two functions in module A. Where one function sends the data to B, and the other function receives some confirm message from B.

But after looking at some UDP example codes on the internet, I realized every example code did the above all in the main function.(socket creation, sendto recvfrom). So I was wondering if splitting the UDP procedure into separate functions is not possible in the first place. And if so, then is it possible to write the UDP procedure all in one function, which is not the main function? Or should all the UDP procedures all be in the main function?

Comment: Not necessarily, but you should certainly arrange to use one UDP socket for the life of the process, rather than opening and closing them all the time.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Thank you!